# Stylus under Gulp: round up all decimal globally

Tags: gulp, stylus

I use the plugin npm [gulp-stylus](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-stylus) to generate my style sheets. As Internet Explorer does not drop below 3 decimals (EDIT 16/11/2015 : 2 decimals!) I would round up all my digits **globally** :

```
// => code output :
width: 83.33%;
```

With gulp-sass I added an option directly from the Gulpfile.js file like this:

```
// Gulpfile.js (code for Sass)
return sass(source + '/Styles', {
      style: 'compressed',
      precision: 2 // it's here
  })
```

But I do not know how to gulp-in Stylus as the plugin page is not very explicit... I just know do individually:

```
.test
  //width (100% / 12 * 10)
  width floor(100% / 12 * 10, 2) // or round(), or ceil()... according to needs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no such settings in gulp-stylus. But you can use postcss plugin for it.
Use regexp pattern for processing float numbers **/(\d+?.\d{3,})(%|em|px)/gi**

```
// Load the PostCSS module.
var postcss = require('postcss');
var post    = require('gulp-postcss');

// Define the plugin.
var precision = postcss.plugin('postcss-precision', function() {
  var longTest = /(\d+?\.\d{3,})(%|em|px)/gi;

  return function(style) {
    style.eachDecl(function(decl) {


      if (! decl.value || longTest.test(decl.value)) {
        // Grab array of matches.
        var matches = longTest.exec(decl.value + '');

        // We'll assume there's one.
        var value = matches[1];

        // Round two decimal places.
        var rounded = Math.round(parseFloat(value) * 100) / 100;

        // Change the value in the tree.
        decl.value = decl.value.replace(value, rounded.toString());
      }
    });
  };
});

// Make PostCSS aware of this plugin.
postcss().use(precision);

gulp.task('css', function() {
  return gulp.src([
      'src/**/*.css'
    ])
    .pipe(post([precision()]))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/css'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['css']);
```

Comment: Ok thank you.

Stylus A contributor to whom we asked the question goes in the same direction you also offering a solution through PostCSS: [GitHub issue](https://github.com/stylus/stylus/issues/2024#issuecomment-157183154).

I probably will choose a solution from case to case, but thank you for your detailed solution.